# Provision product with strip and dj-stripe

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe with DRF and on top of that, I've implemented the library dj-stripe.

Everything works so far but I'm not really sure how to provision my product now. I do have access to the `subscription` and `customer` object for every user but these objects are quite complicated / big. I can't really do something like `if user.subscription -> do this` since the subscription could be e. g. `deleted`, `inactive`. I also need a more granular solution since I need to apply limits like:

```
if subscription.plan.product === "Entry Plan":
   # allow user to only create 5 instances
```

I can't really find information on how to do this elegantly and consistently for an entire app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the [Subscription object](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/models.html#subscription) for a customer, then yes you will need to check the [`status`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-status) of the Subscription to ensure it's still active. dj-stripe appears to have a [helper](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/models.html#djstripe.models.Subscription.is_status_current) for this.

The implementation of provisioning access to your application/products is up to you, because it depends heavily on your business needs. If you have specific questions about challenges beyond the subscription status, I suggesting asking those clearly so that they can be addressed, but there is no concise way to explain how to generally provision access.

As I side note, I recommended reaching out to the author of `dj-stripe` with a thank you and ask what you can do to help get the [docs for checking subscriptions](https://dj-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/checking_customer_subscription.html) fleshed out.